# regex replacement question

Tags: php, regex

How can I alter this callback so that it sends matches on the keyword "test" in all cases where there is not a ">" character preceeding the keyword? And only matches on the whole word, (ie, does not match on "testing")

```
$theContent = preg_replace_callback("/\b('test')\b/i","doReplace", $content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a negative lookbehind:

```
/\b(?<!>)(test)\b/
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Been pulling my hair out with this one :)